# Keep Date format to be fix IPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, datepicker, nsdateformatter

How do I keep the date format fix getting from UIDatePickerView, It should not affected from country(Region Format). Presently In my application if I set the region format as "China" it is displaying UIDatePickerView in local china format. I want to as it is but I want to access the date from this in my fixed standard format. It should not be affect by country whether it is Australia or  China or UK. Please Suggest with example.

I do not want to change the date format in Picker View just want to change date format access from it. Here is the code that I am using:

```
NSDateFormatter *datef = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

        NSCalendar *usersCalendar =
        [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];
        [datef setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        [datef setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
         [datef setCalendar:usersCalendar];

        tempFDate = [datef dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",txtDate.text,txtTime.text]];

        NSLog(@"%@",tempFDate);
```

I am continuously getting null in console. I need such a date format that can work for all the region formats. Please Suggest its urgent for me.

Comment: set locale to date picker it will display always in one format

Comment: I want to show the Date Picker in localFormat but I need to access date in my standard format.

Comment: then set your date standard format to dateFormater

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720708/setting-uidatepicker-date-with-nsdateformatter

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, just do a `setDateFormat` on your NSDateFormatter after you create it.  Then it will (mostly) obey that format rather than the default locale's format.  (You realize, of course, you can have as many different NSDateFormatters as you want, with different settings.)

Comment: Yes, You are right. it works for mostly but I think not for all region format.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDateformatter`  is the best option.
See, the timezone if not specified it will use the timezone of which device is set and display the content accordingly

there are options to get the device setted timezone also to work with it

```
+ localTimeZone
+ defaultTimeZone
+ setDefaultTimeZone:
+ resetSystemTimeZone
+ systemTimeZone
```

check this [class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here you need the reponse to a certain timezone for eg GMT 0000
then

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

will do the job for you

Comment: Its not working for me. As I select region format of device as "China" or "Arabic".

Answer (score 0):

using NSDateFormatter.

you can use NSDateFormatter to convert any date format like dd/MM/yyyy etc.

Comment: This will need to setDate Format for all the countries. As we get different date format from China and different in Australia.

Comment: This is not work if I set the region format of device is Arabic or China.